# Hibernate JPA Persistence Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception

I'm trying to test my hibernate mapping based on a set of given JUnit tests. The following test however fails.

```
@Test
public void testEntity3Constraint() {
    expectedException.expect(PersistenceException.class);
    expectedException.expectCause(isA(ConstraintViolationException.class));

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        // Entity #3
        IUplink ent3_1 = daoFactory.getUplinkDAO().findById(testData.entity3_1Id);
        ent3_1.setName(TestData.N_ENT3_2);
        em.persist(ent3_1);
        em.flush();

    } finally {
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Expected: (an instance of javax.persistence.PersistenceException and exception with cause is an 
     instance of org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException)
but: exception with cause is an instance of org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException cause 
     <org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: dst.ass1.jpa.model.impl.UplinkImpl> 
     is a org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException
```

As you can see The Constraint Violations and Persistence Exceptions are swapped in terms of instance and cause. The exception is thrown when I'm calling `entitymanager.persist`. How can I obtain the expected exception?

I cannot change the expected exception and nor do I want to. I need to find a way to get the exception expected by the test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you do `expectedException.expect(ConstraintViolationException.class);`, am I missing something?

Comment: The tests are given and I am not allowed to alter them, so now I'm looking for a way to get the exception the test requires

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`
but get a similar yet different `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException`.

Just change the Exception you expect in your test.

Comment: Thank you, I could have done that myself. I need the opposite of that. I want to change the thrown Exception in order to match the expected one

Comment: You will have to create your own EntityManager then.